# Pycharm installation

Tags: linux, software-installation

I have installed pycharm from source and used the shell script to install it. I have a problem with running it, how do i run it? how do I know if software should be run from a shell script or from executable etc ...

Comment: Did you run in with graphic environment started?

Comment: when installation was done GUI popped up and i could use it, do you mean if i used the command to enable GUI when configuring it?

Comment: Could you add how do extracted and executed the installation script.

Comment: i just downloaded the tar.gz file and then they mentioned i should execute the pycharm.sh

Comment: i should add i dont have root priveliges, but that shouldnt be a problem since it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the tarball is extracted under `/opt` (recommended by the pycharm docs).

Create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /opt/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh /usr/local/bin/pycharm
```

Then :

```
pycharm
```

For non root user, create an alias, add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias  pycharm='/storage/my_user/software/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh'
```

Save file then run: `exec bash`

Comment: does it matter where i extract the tarball? or you mean the link should point out to wherever my tarball is?

Comment: @QUTADAH if it doesn't `/opt`, replace it with your own directory.

Comment: The tarball only contains the material. The link needs to point to `pycharm.sh`.

Comment: i tried creating a symbolic link, permission denied, (i am not root user)

Comment: @QUTADAH Where you have extracted the tarball? I will edit my answer.

Comment: /storage/my_user/software/

Comment: i should also note when i run pycharm.sh script now, gui opens but i cannot click anything and a weird pointer shows, i can only click the x or close button

Answer (score 0):

As described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html#standalone:

---

Switch to the bin subdirectory:

```
cd <new archive folder>/pycharm-*/bin
```

For example,

```
cd /opt/pycharm-*/bin
```

Run pycharm.sh from the bin subdirectory.

```
sh pycharm.sh
```

---

Comment: thats what i did but this is for installation, my question is how to run it again after installation

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't now understand. The way to start the application doesn't change over time. If it's started immediately after the installation running `pycharm.sh` -script in this directory, it's always started the same way. If `pycharm.sh` didn't actually start the application but is an installer script, it's a different ballgame - but I'm fairly sure the instructions are still found in the guide. One way to simplify it is creating a link as @GAD3R suggests, another is creating a new alias.

Comment: i installed it with pycharm.sh, you mean to say if it ran with this it means i should always use this script to run it?

Comment: Mate I'm not familiar with pycharm. I can only read the manual which I linked. I assume you're as capable of reading the manual as I am, and since you're the one who needs the tool I would assume you have a bit more incentive to get to know how it actually works than I do.

Comment: yes it says i should run it same way.. do you have an idea why now i cant click anything in the gui after running script as specified?

Comment: Let's start by you actually ***READING THE MANUAL***. It took me 5 seconds to figure out it contains a section _Support and assistance_, which contains _Using online resources_ and _Troubleshooting Pycharm_.

Comment: I have been working on it since yesterday, maybe youre experienced and know within 5 minutes how to get around it, i have been googling and reading the manual since yesterday.

Comment: No, I just looked at the manual page, right hand side, down, to find the sections I referred to. ***If you've read the guide since yesterday, how's it possible you don't know how to start the application?*** What you describe now is no longer your original question but a different issue. You should accept here the answer that resolved the how-to-start -question and ask a new one describing your current issue, in detail please, including what you've already tried to resolve the issue. The more vague and without supporting info your questions are, the more difficult it is for us to help you.